# INNER JOIN SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

Buen día colegas, estoy realizando unas consultas en la BD NorthWind.

Pero aun no logro obtener el resultado que deseo.

Tengo que obtener el total de ordenes por empleado, en la consulta que ya realice ya me da el total de ordenes junto con el nombre del empleado, pero no logro agregar también el ID del empleado.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

```
SELECT FirstName as Empleado, COUNT (orderID) as Total_de_ordenes
FROM Orders INNER JOIN Employees on Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID     
GROUP BY (Employees.FirstName)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder "agrupar" lo vamos a hacer de la siguiente manera, no puedo probarlo así que a lo mejor se me escapa un "typo" pero lo he revisado varias veces.

En tu caso:

```
SELECT 
    Employees.FirstName as Empleado, 
    Employees.EmployeeID as EmpleadoID, 
    COUNT (orderID) as Total_de_ordenes
FROM Orders 
    INNER JOIN Employees on Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID     
GROUP BY 
    Employees.FirstName, 
    Employees.EmployeeID
```

Los cambios que he realizado en tu consulta son muy sencillos. He añadido tanto en el `select` como en el `group by` el campo por el que queríamos agrupar y a su vez mostrar.

Te dejo el enlace a la documentación para que le eches un vistazo:

[SELECT: GROUP BY (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, te agradezco la contribución de la documentación